# When an item in a population doesn't match the "group-by" in an "for-each-group", can it be assigned to a group with an empty current-group-key()?

Tags: xslt-2.0

So I have input like:

```
<Root>
 <Item id="1" group="foo" />
 <Item id="2" group="bar" />
 <Item id="3" />
</Root>
```

And a template instruction like:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Root" group-by="@group" />
```

It would seem that I only get groups for `foo` and `bar`. (Why?  I expected I might get a 3rd group with `current-group-key() = ''`).

I really want that 3rd group.  What options do I have?

thanks,
David.

Comment: using `group-by="concat('',@group)"` gives me the 3rd group.  I'm still not clear why group-by behaves it behaves the way it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSLT 2.0 specification http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group says the following about `group-by`:

> If the group-by attribute is present, the items in the population are
>   examined, in population order. For each item J, the expression in the
>   group-by attribute is evaluated to produce a sequence of zero or more
>   grouping key values. For each one of these grouping keys, if there is
>   already a group created to hold items having that grouping key value,
>   J is added to that group; otherwise a new group is created for items
>   with that grouping key value, and J becomes its first member.
>
> An item in the population may thus be assigned to zero, one, or many
>   groups.

So in your case when the `group-by` expression `@group` is evaluated for the third `Item` element it evaluates to the empty sequence and thus there is no grouping key found causing the item to be added to any group. That way the third `Item` does not belong to any group.

Comment: Ah ha!  I read that paragraph at least once before posting, but it didn't make sense until now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Martin gave a good explanation.

If what you want is allowed, then elements that don't have a `group` attribute at all, would be in the same group as elements that do have a `group=''` attribute -- and this is not precise.

**The simplest solution is to indicate in the `group-by` attribute that whether or not a `group` attribute exists doesn't matter**.

The simplest way to do so is:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Root/*" group-by="string(@group)">
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Root/*" group-by="string(@group)">
   "<xsl:sequence select="string(@group)"/>"
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Root>
    <Item id="1" group="foo" />
    <Item id="2" group="bar" />
    <Item id="3" />
</Root>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
   "foo"

   "bar"

   ""
```

Comment: That helped to cement it with a practical example.  Thanks.